# Filter ng-options based on multiple controls or ng-models

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

**Situation:**

I have a back-end Laravel 5 and front-end AngularJS. Application is about allowing users to select multiple dependent very high-value products.

A. User selects a product from a drop-down - select-option. Product is added to a cart.

B. Then user clicks on Add button to add more products, this adds a row dynamically with drop-down select-option HTML element. This is done dynamically using AngularJS with $compile / $scope to add compiled HTML.

C. When user adds a row, initially product drop-down select-option has no value selected.

D. User selects a product from drop-down select-option. Product is added to a cart.

E. User may keep on adding around 50 products.
Look at this UI:

[image: UI Looks like]

Now the condition is, when a new row is added the relevant drop-down should not show any product that is already selected in any of the drop-downs above.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this. hope it will work.**
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.rep = [];
  $scope.xyz = function(){
    var sahed = $filter('filter')($scope.rep, $scope.sel) ;
    if(sahed.length <= 0){
       $scope.rep.push($scope.sel)
       return false;
    }

  };
  $scope.coll =[
   {id: 1,
   rate : 50,
   base_price : 50,
     product_name : 'ab'
   },
   {id: 2,
   rate : 50,
   base_price : 505,
    product_name : 'abc' 
   },
   {id: 3,
   rate : 520,
   base_price : 500,
     product_name : 'abcd'
   },
   {id: 4,
   rate : 50,
   base_price : 505,
    product_name : 'abcef' 
   },
  ];
});
```

and here the html

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select name="sel" id="sel" ng-model="sel"
    ng-options="x as x.product_name for x in coll track by x.id" ng-change="xyz()">
      <option value="">select product</option>
    </select>
    <table border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>price</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in rep">
          <td>{{x.product_name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.base_price}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

For example see it https://plnkr.co/edit/pXNkwisa7A3aFBPmIB0G?p=preview